# Do Perl 6 POSIX character classes respect the LOCALE?

Tags: regex, posix, locale, raku

Does Perl 6 POSIX character classes respect the LOCALE? I was playing with a program that would print all the characters matching a POSIX char class, and it seems to always print the same set no matter what I set my locale too. If my locale is `en_US.US-ASCII`, I still get 520ish digits. It's also annoying that doing this on a Mac means I don't have the cool locale exploration tools found elsewhere (or, they are there under different names).

This is all under this command which I need to make into a shell alias:

```
$ perl6 -e 'say join " ", map *.gist, $*VM, $*PERL, $*DISTRO, $*KERNEL'
moar (2016.10) Perl 6 (6.c) macosx (10.10.5) darwin (14.5.0)
```

And, the program:

```
my $properties = set( <
    alnum alpha ascii blank cntrl digit graph lower print graph punct
    space upper word xdigit
    > );

sub MAIN ( Str $property where * ∈ $properties = 'digit' ) {
    say "NAME is " ~ %*ENV<NAME>;
    say "LC_CTYPE is " ~ ( %*ENV<LC_CTYPE> // %*ENV<LC_ALL> );
    say "property is $property";
    use MONKEY-SEE-NO-EVAL;


    my $pattern = EVAL "rx/ <$property> /";
    say "regex is " ~ $pattern.gist;

    show_chars( $pattern );
    }

sub show_chars ( Regex $pattern ) {
    for 0 .. 0x10FFFF -> $codepoint {
        state $count = 0;
        LAST { say "\nThere were $count characters" }
        my $char = chr( $codepoint );
        next unless $char ~~ $pattern;
        $count++;

        print "$char ";
        print "\n" if $count %% 50;
        }
    }
```

Notice I do a stupid EVAL thing in the program. I was looking for a replacement for variable interpolation in `rx`. S05 indicates it was a thing, but there's no docs for it so I guess it isn't. I started to explore my own tokens, but had to move on. And, now I've asked [a separate question about the interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40883160/2766176).

Answer (score 6):

To the best of my knowledge, Perl 6 regexes do not support POSIX character classes. The built-in methods you mentioned map to Unicode properties or blocks (or similar constructs, pardon my Unicode ignorance), and none of them are Locale specific.

As far as the EVAL is concerned, you can get rid of it like this:

```
my $re_string = '<alpha>';
say 'a' ~~ rx / <$re_string> /;
```

Comment: If they don't support them, then we need to fix the docs to not say "POSIX character classes" https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes

Comment: As far as I can tell, that doesn't do variable interpolation. It binds to the variable and uses it's value when the regex is executed.

Comment: Fixed by moritz in https://github.com/perl6/doc/commit/5b79e4988c1417ee94e417335bf3edbba3016d06

Answer (score 2):

**2019 update** Many links don't work. Some are gone for good, some temporarily, some have replacements.<sup>1</sup>

About this answer:

> Thanks for the work! FWIW, I didn't care about locales at all. I just saw "POSIX" and was surprised the Perl 6 would care about that. – brian d foy
>
> Thanks. I saw that Moritz had already answered your SO before I started. But I decided I wanted to spelunk the repos etc. looking for matches of the string 'locale'. ... Then I decided it would be useful to publish these results and that they would be more useful here, where someone searching for perl6 and locale might find them, than as just a personal gist. – raiph

---

## Mentions of 'locale' in relevant Perl 6 and/or Rakudo documents

I'm not directly addressing your narrow question about POSIX and regexes. Moritz has answered that. This post is just me documenting my broad search for answers to the more general question of "What support is there for *any* locale specific processing in Perl 6 and/or Rakudo?" by searching for matches of 'locale' in various repos and the like.

This "answer" combines definitive sources with wild speculation. If it's linked, it's definitive. If it's my prose, it's wild speculation.

[A search for 'locale' in the existing public module list](http://modules.perl6.org/#q=locale) yields 3 modules. Afaict, none affect Perl 6 behavior.

[A google search of docs.perl6.org for 'locale'](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocs.perl6.org+locale) yields "Your search - site:docs.perl6.org locale - did not match any documents."

An in-page search for 'locale' at [perl6.fail](http://perl6.fail) yields a single [bug report](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=116709#ticket-history).

[A google search of the design/speculation docs](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:design.perl6.org+locale) yields three results of interest:

1. A `locale` method. It looks like it was a long ago specified way to find out what the current OS locale is or somesuch. [A search of Rakudo's source for 'locale'](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=locale) yields zero matches.
2. Mention of deliberately *not* handling time locale processing in core.
3. Mention of a built in rule `<blank>` which matches "a single 'blank' character -- in most locales, this corresponds to space and tab.". This rule is implemented as [the `blank` method on the `Cursor` class in NQP](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/42313ae7eac2bd46ed9c002334f95647618736fd/src/QRegex/Cursor.nqp#L749). The code `say so " \t" ~~ / <blank>+ /` returns `True` using my system.

[A search of NQP's source for 'locale'](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=locale) yields zero matches.

[A search of MoarVM's repo for 'locale'](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=locale) yields matches in the third party GCC libatomic library (a library of portable atomic operations; I've no idea why such code should care about `locale`).

[A google search for 'locale' in #perl6](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Airclog.perlgeek.de+inurl%3Aperl6#q=site:irclog.perlgeek.de+inurl:perl6+%2B%22locale%22) yields a bunch of mentions including:

- 2007 TimToady: ["at the standard unicode level ... locales are completely ignored"](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2007-12-07#i_158601). And "but if you ask for language dependent character processing, you can ask it to pay attention to a locale". (I don't think anyone has yet written the code necessary for the latter.)
- 2008 No one answers Moritz (who wrote the other answer to this question above) when he asks ["any idea how locales will be handled in Perl 6?"](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2008-04-17#i_263624).
- 2012 TimToady says ["we tend to dislike locales intensely"](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2012-08-26#i_5930958).
- 2016 ["some standard locale stuff for dates, numbers and stuff would be useful"](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-02-05#i_11993917)
- 2016 ["i don't think we have locale-aware formatting of numbers"](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-09-11#i_13189480).
- 2016 ["Perl 6 doesn't handle anything locale-specific such as those Turkish special cases AFAIK."](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-09-19#i_13236429)

## Footnotes

1 Many links in this answer are broken in 2019:

- perl6.fail is gone for good. Use the rt bug tracker, perl6 queue, and gh issue queues for perl6 and rakudo instead. The rt tracker is going away and is currently read only.
- design.perl6.org is down at the moment, perhaps for good. The best substitute I know is [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190202080246/https://design.perl6.org/). But afaik that's not searchable across pages.
- irclog.perlgeek.de links are down for good. The best substitute I know is [colabti's irclog](https://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/perl6) which goes back to about 2009 or so. (Moritz's perlgeek data went back to 2005.) Use the date in the URL to map over to colabti's log.

Comment: Thanks for the work! FWIW, I didn't care about locales at all. I just saw "POSIX" and was surprised the Perl 6 would care about that.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that Moritz had already answered your SO before I started. But I decided I wanted to spelunk the repos etc. looking for matches of the string 'locale'. I occasionally do this sort of thing as a sort of audit of Perl 6 progress relative to some aspect and as a sanity test of the accuracy of my sense of said progress. So I searched. Then I decided it would be useful to publish these results and that they would be more useful here, where someone searching for `perl6` and `locale` might find them, than as just a personal gist.

Comment: 2 things. (1) most of the links don't work =\ (2) I am working on a very large localization / internationalization project.  I hadn't thought about it before, but there *are* psuedo-character class data that I could grab out of the CLDR (for example, "letters commonly used in the language" or "punctuation used in the language") and make available in some capacity.  I've already figured out a way to make a psuedo locale-sensitive regex date matcher, and am absolutely willing to look at ways to integrate some of that data in useful ways.

Comment: For determining the locale, though, my `Intl::UserLanguage` → `user-language()` seems to do the same as the proposed `locale()`.  Perhaps I should modify the name of the method so it can be used as a shim until core support comes?

Comment: Hi @guifa. (1) Thanks for the heads up about broken links. I've added a note to the answer that provides alternatives. That said I think I summarized the key things so that the original sources probably don't matter. (2) Do you mean you're working on a large P6 project? My own sense of things is that several years of persistent improvement of P6's l10n/i18n will transform P6's worldwide relevance and adoption more than any other single thing I can think of *provided it includes TGC work*. But I recommend you ask Larry/Jonathan for input on what to prioritize and how to package and evolve it.

Comment: @raiph unfortunately I'm abroad right now but when I'm back stateside with solid internet I'll hop on #perl6 to talk about it. Some of the initial work is in `Intl::CLDR` but as I'm going the plan is to spin that off into just the data and have other Intl modules for date/number format, detection (to use, for instance, as a <local-date> grammar token, etc), localized sorting, and support a generalized l10n framework (I've been working on Mozilla's Fluent, but I'll go towards maketext and others next).

Comment: @guifa Sounds great. If you need related grunt work done, just leave another comment here and I'll try help. I must emphasize that I think making progress on Rakudo's use of [Tailored Grapheme Clusters](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Tailored+Grapheme+Clusters%22) should utterly dominate [the critical path](https://www.google.com/search?q=critical+path). (1) NFG is P6's strategic differentiator. (2) NFG == EGC is flashy default but useless without TGCs. (3) Globally relevant locale handling relies on TGC support. (4) Imo locals will help build out l10n if P6 leads the world in TGC support.